# BigDecimal divide no rounding

Tags: java

I have this code to divide a BigDecimal for 1000000.

I had tried RoundingMode.DOWN, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN.

```java
public static BigDecimal divide1000000(BigDecimal aBigDecimal) {
        if(aBigDecimal!=null)
            return aBigDecimal.divide(new BigDecimal("1000000"));

        return aBigDecimal;
}

BigDecimal B= new BigDecimal("99999999999999999"); /*99,999,999,999,999,999*/
BigDecimal a=divide1000000(B);
```

> result a=100000000000 (100,000,000,000)

If I want

> result a = 99999999999 (99,999,999,999)

How can I change divide1000000?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. If I add `System.out.println(a);` below your two statements, I see `99999999999.999999` as you would expect. It looks you haven't posted the code you're running, See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the RoundingMode you are looking for is ROUND_DOWN or ROUND_FLOOR. You can use any one of them. here are all:-

```
BigDecimal a= new BigDecimal("99999999999.999999");
BigDecimal b= new BigDecimal(0);
b = a.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP); // 100000000000
b = a.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING); // 100000000000
b = a.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN); // 99999999999
b = a.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR); // 99999999999
b = a.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // 100000000000
b = a.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN); // 100000000000
b = a.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); // 100000000000
```

You can use either of ROUND_DOWN or ROUND_FLOOR.